# Cannot use AWS in PCL project

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, xamarin, portable-class-library

In my PCL project I have added the following two NuGet packages:

- `AWSSDK.Core`
- `AWSSDK.S3`

To use them like this

```
private AmazonS3Client _client;
private TransferUtility _trans;

public MyClass()
{
    AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config ();
    config.ServiceURL = "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com";
    config.UseHttp = true;
    config.RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUWest1;

    _client = new AmazonS3Client (_access, _secret, config);
    _trans = new TransferUtility (_client);
}

public async void UploadFile(string path, string key)
{
    TransferUtilityUploadRequest up = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest();
    up.BucketName = "mybucket";
    up.FilePath = path;
    up.Key = key;

    up.UploadProgressEvent += up_UploadProgressEvent;
    await _trans.UploadAsync(up);
}
```

Now when I try to test this method using `NUnit` I get the following error

> This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this
>   assembly.  You should reference the PCLStorage NuGet package from your
>   main application project in order to reference the platform-specific
>   implementation.

StackTrace being

```
at PCLStorage.FileSystem.get_Current()
   at Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility.validate(TransferUtilityUploadRequest request) in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\S3\Custom\Transfer\TransferUtility.cs:line 367
   at Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility.GetUploadCommand(TransferUtilityUploadRequest request, SemaphoreSlim asyncThrottler) in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\S3\Custom\Transfer\_async\TransferUtility.async.cs:line 281
   at Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility.UploadAsync(TransferUtilityUploadRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\Jenkins\jobs\v3-stage-release\workspace\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\S3\Custom\Transfer\_async\TransferUtility.async.cs:line 184
```

Comment: I guess that you cant simply test this using a unit test project. probably sdk doesnt support test project over PCL version. I have the same problem using UWP application.

Answer (score 0):

You should add Core and S3 packages also in your platform specific project.

If you are using Xamarin you have to add the packages in the PCL and also in your android or iOS projects.